Meaning of the phase of a sample
In a sampled signal RF signal with I,Q parts, if we represent each sample as an amplitude and phase, what does the phase of a sample mean? Does it say something about the RF signal at that point of time in time domain?

This is literally the first thing I explained when I introduced I and Q signals in my hall exercises. Are you sure the literature you're learning "I,Q" from doesn't explain how the complex numbers map to the inphase and quadrature oscillators? Other than that, the accepted answer here explains all your questions:

Does this answer your question? Is the phase of a IQ point related to the local oscillator frequency?

I do get one's confusion with this, it's typically the first thing I need to clear up with new students and often takes a lot longer than I would think to clear up stemming I believe in how ingrained sine waves are for us to visualize individual frequencies tones. For that reason I avoid using sine waves to explain signal processing.

I think there is a common confusion with "phase" as used in signal processing, and it is often incorrectly conflated with "time delay". I believe this originates in our introduction to phase as the difference between two sine waves offset in time. Although that is mathematically correct as time delay maps to a phase for a single frequency, I believe it leaves many with a fundamental misunderstanding and confusion on use of phase in signal processing, especially when we then move on to signals that occupy more than one bandwidth.
For use in signal processing, phase is the angle of a sample on the complex plane, and is therefore applicable to complex signals. We can work with complex signals in time or frequency (or other domains), and in all cases a phase shift for a particular sample would be a rotation on the complex plane.
My favorite question "How do you build a DC source with 45 degrees" is a test if you are indeed conflating phase with time delay. Those that are stuck with the time delay approach to creating a phase shift for a single tone would come to the conclusion that it is impossible to build such a device (it would require an infinite delay!!). How we do build such a device is to have two real sources (one labeled "I" for in phase representing the amplitude of the signal along the real axis, and the other labeled "Q" for quadrature representing the amplitude of the signal along the imaginary axis), and to adjust this one (I,Q) source to 45 degrees, we make the I and Q values equal. It's a DC source as it stays at these values for all time.
Note too that the phase for every sample that is real is always $0°$ or $180°$. The function $x(t)= cos(\omega t)$ maps a phase parameter given by $\omega t$ to a real value, and as such the phase of that real value is always $0°$ when positive or $180°$ when negative. In order for us to have an $x(t)$ with other phase values, it must be complex. The function $x(t) = e^{j\omega t}$ is a function with a time varying phase (rotating counter-clockwise on the complex plane at a constant rate for a positive real $\omega$).  The two are related with Euler's formulas:
$$e^{j\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + j\sin(\omega t)$$
$$2\cos(\omega t) = e^{j\omega t} + e^{-j\omega t}$$
Which is saying that a real cosine wave (which itself only has a phase that can be 0° or 180°) is the sum of two spinning phasors on the complex plane with complex conjugate phase, such that one is spinning counter-clockwise and the other clock-wise, adding the two given equal magnitude and opposite phase (complex conjugate symmetry) will always be a result on the real axis.
In the radio design world where I am from, we often see "I" and "Q" in hardware implementations. One complex sample has two real numbers associated with it (I,Q) where I is the amplitude of the real component and Q is the amplitude of the imaginary component. Thus each individual sample is represented as an ordered pair of real numbers (I,Q) or I+jQ. We do the same thing on paper; we need to have two real numbers to represent a single complex number (either $I+jQ$ or $Ae^{j\phi}$). Thus each of these samples has a magnitude and phase. With that we can implement directly at baseband (carrier = 0 Hz, or DC!) the instantaneous magnitude and phase of a signal, that we can then translate to any other carrier. Further, when that carrier is greater than the overall bandwidth of our signal, we can proceed to take the real part alone (resulting in the passband signal) without any loss of information!  [and if that last sentence isn't clear, that can be the topic of another question].
(In case the exponential notation is somewhat foreign, note the geometric interpretation of $Ae^{j\phi}$ is $A\angle{\phi}$ for real $A, \phi$).

@ajoy did this answer help or if not can you comment on what is confusing you about it?
